# API call with setInterval causing too many re-renders React

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, setinterval

I am making two API calls, and I am using setInterval for one of my calls as I would like to request new information every minute. However, this is causing the component to re-render every minute, which also results in additional requests for my second API call. How can I prevent this from happening, I don't want multiple requests for my second API call.

```
const FetchData = () => {
  const [quote, setQuote] = useState("");
  const [time, setTime] = useState("");

   console.log(quote);
   console.log(time);

   useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
     setInterval(async () => {
        const time = await axios.get("http://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip");
        setTime(time.data);
      }, 6000);

      // I'd like to prevent this call from being requested multiple times
      const quote = await axios.get("https://api.quotable.io/random");
      setQuote(quote.data);

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: There is no code here that would call the second endpoint more than twice. The problem must be somewhere else. You should also clear your intervals in `useEffect`

Comment: When i do a console.log, I can see it being called multiple times. 
```console.log(quote);
      console.log(time);
```

Comment: So maybe your `FetchData` component is rendered multiple times. Or there is another part of the code that you didn't show that triggers it

Comment: Yes I believe the ```FetchData``` component is re-rendered multiple times due to the ```setInterval```. Should these API calls be made in separate components then? I haven't really written much code at this point that would trigger this.

Comment: Rerendering this component will not call `fetchData` again, because it's called in `useEffect`